# C# data chart in x axis shows multiple times cities windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Guru's please halp this poor padawan.

I'm trying to display a chart with the values that i gave in my database. In the X- Axis I only want for example one City called "Rotterdam", but it gives me multiple times Rotterdam in the x-axis from other rows.

[The chart where I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLjdj.png)

this is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.fietsdiefstalTableAdapter.Fill(this.official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal);

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series["Fietsdiefstal"].XValueMember = "Plaats";
            chart1.Series["Fietsdiefstal"].YValueMembers = "Begintijd";







            chart1.DataSource = official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal;
            chart1.DataBind();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                fietsdiefstalBindingSource.EndEdit();
                fietsdiefstalTableAdapter.Update(official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal);
                MessageBox.Show("Your data has been succesfully saved.", " Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void chart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.fietsdiefstalTableAdapter.FillBy(this.official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void time1300ToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.fietsdiefstalTableAdapter.Time1300(this.official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void timeToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.fietsdiefstalTableAdapter.Time(this.official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal, param1ToolStripTextBox.Text);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void param1ToolStripLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void straatToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.fietsdiefstalTableAdapter.Straat(this.official_DatabaseDataSet.fietsdiefstal, param1ToolStripTextBox1.Text);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the docs on [Asking Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  You should provide much more detail on your question and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: Is this better now?

Comment: Much!  I'll remove my downvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like you are using the `fietsdiefstal` data for both your datagrid and your chart.

You should make a second data set that aggregates your results into the format you desire.  You can do this in C# or in whatever language you're using to fill the data tables (I'm assuming SQL?)

So, for example, in SQL the query should look something like

```
SELECT City, SUM(SomeValue) FROM MyTable
GROUP BY City
```

In which `City` is the column you will use to populate the X-Axis and `SomeValue` is what the Bar height will be.

If you want to do it in C#, you will want need to loop over the records.  Something like:

```
var aggregateData = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
{
    int val;
    aggregateData.TryGetValue(row["City"], out val);
    aggregateData[row["City"]] = val + row["SomeValue"];
}
```

(I have not tested these example)

Comment: Damn what you said i was thinking about but could not figure yet how i could do it. I'll check tonight if it works! Thank you!